# Phusion Baseimage vs. Phusion Passenger (Can I install NGINX easily on baseimage?)

Tags: docker, nginx, passenger, phusion

Building a Phusion+NGINX+Gunicorn+Django web stack inside  docker container, doccumenting [on github](https://github.com/HarryCaveMan/site-test/tree/master/mysite). I have the container running with django and gunicorn. I would like to set up an NGINX reverse proxy. Originally, my plan was just to add something like this(assuming that my bseimage is derived from trusty):

```
#cat NGINX repos to sources.list

RUN cat ../../etc/apt/sources.list >> debrepos.txt

#install nginx
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nginx
```

Where the file `debrepos.txt` has the following:

```
#stanzas for nginx
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
#deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
#deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
```

From there I would replace the `nginx.conf` file with the one I need. Recently, I found out about passenger. So my real questions are a.)will the above work in phusion-baseimage? and b.)should I just start over and do this using passenger and `docker_compose.yml`?

P.S. Let me know if I should include the full dockerfile from my repo. I left it out in the name of minimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger author here. We have a passenger-docker baseimage which is based on baseimage-docker: https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker
It already contains Nginx.

Comment: Will this allow me to use the same dockerfile to copy the app directories and install requirements, by just changing the build image? If it is essentially that should conclude this issue. Thanks for being so prompt!

Comment: Which image would you recommend for nginx and python 2.7? I am looking at [this](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker#image_variants).

Comment: Went with `phusion/passenger-custoimizable:0.9.24 ` and installed python. There was a slight hangup during the build but it seems that it did not affect performance. `dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:`